# execute ajax inside condition before execute next ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two tables in a database , when pressing the submit button I want to insert new trader into trader table and get id using  `laravel 5.2` by using post ajax under condition ,then execute another post ajax for invoice insert , but the problem in this case is when I press the submit it execute second ajax before the first ajax .. why?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('#invoiceForm').validate({

    //rules: itemRules,

    errorPlacement: function (element) {
        return false;
    },
    submitHandler: function (event) {
        //event.preventDefault();
       // $('#selectedTraderName').valid();
        var allItems = [];
        $('tr.inputsItem').each(function () {
         rowData = $(this).children('td').find('.form-control').map(function () {
            return $(this).val();
        }).get();
            rowData.push(parseInt($(this).children('td').find('strong#autoTotal').text().trim()));
            if($('select[id=selectedTraderName]').val() <= lastTraderID) {
                rowData.push($('select[id=selectedTraderName]').val());
            }
            else{
                newTrader = [];
                newTrader.push($('#name').val());
                newTrader.push($('#traderMail').val());
                newTrader.push($('#mobileNumber').val());
                newTrader.push($('#address').val());
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: insertNewTrader,
                    data:{_token:token, trader:newTrader}
                }).done(function (msg) {
                    rowData.push(msg['id']);
                });

            }
            alert(rowData[6]);
            allItems.push(rowData);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: insertNewItem,
                data:{_token:token, items:allItems}
            }).done(function () {
                alert('done');
            });
        });


    }

});
```

Comment: Not a proper way but, you could set function state in a variable and verify it in setInterval and execute it after the function 1 has completed. If you are really using this, then do remember to change function state and remove interval properly.

Comment: You say you want to execute one ajax inside another ajax's handler but you do not have the second ajax inside the first's .done handler

Comment: Call the second ajax request inside first ajax's sucess

Comment: Don't you think that you can do all this in one ajax request?

Comment: Why not just create the invoice on the server side when you create a new trader?

Comment: i have two condition i can't insert invoice without trader id , and if i insert it by the first ajax .. then the another condition how i can do it !!

Comment: why it execute second ajax before the first !!??

Comment: if else condition it execute the second !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can't nest ajax calls because of the `if/else` statement instead you can use a `Deferred object` like this:

```
rowData.push(parseInt($(this).children('td').find('strong#autoTotal').text().trim()));
// Create a new Deferred object
var deferred = $.Deferred();
if ($('select[id=selectedTraderName]').val() <= lastTraderID) {
    rowData.push($('select[id=selectedTraderName]').val());
    //Nothing to wait just resolve the deferred
    deferred.resolve();
} else {
    newTrader = [];
    newTrader.push($('#name').val());
    newTrader.push($('#traderMail').val());
    newTrader.push($('#mobileNumber').val());
    newTrader.push($('#address').val());
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: insertNewTrader,
        data: {
            _token: token,
            trader: newTrader
        }
    }).done(function(msg) {
        rowData.push(msg['id']);
        //Resolve the deferred
        deferred.resolve();
    });

}
//When the deferred resolved then execute your next ajax request
deferred.then(function() {
    allItems.push(rowData);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: insertNewItem,
        data: {
            _token: token,
            items: allItems
        }
    }).done(function() {
        alert('done');
    });
});
```

I hope thsi will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Check the 2nd ajax request condition and call 2nd ajax function on 1st ajax function complete section/success section.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: insertNewItem,
  data:{_token:token, items:allItems},
  complete : function(){
  //call ur 2nd ajax request here
  },
  success : function(data){
  console.log(data);
  //call ur 2nd ajax request here
  }
});
```